# Compiler: code generation for lvalue and rvalue

Tags: compiler-construction

I am writing a small compiler for a java-like language, except that every thing is object in this language, even the primitive type.

Consider the following code:

```
class Main inherits IO {

    fib(x : Int) : Int {
        if x < 2
        then x
        else fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)
        fi
    };

    main() : Object {
        out_int(fib(10))
    };
};
```

In my implementation, everything that pass into a function is a copy of the reference to that object. (so 10 is an integer object). So the `fib` function will also return an integer object.

However, `fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)` requires two function's results to be rvalue, so it can properly perform addition.

I couldn't come up with a automatic way to handle this problem: **how to find a way so that the compiler knows when to generate code for a lvalue and when for a rvalue?**

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can just ignore the difference. Consider `+` as a function that takes two references to integer objects `a,b` and returns the reference to a new object whose value is the sum of `a` and `b`. This function must, of course, be implemented by the compiler but apart from that it should be similar to other functions.